# Where in the code of pytorch or huggingface/transformer label gets "renamed" into labels?

Tags: python, pytorch, huggingface-transformers

My question concerns the example, available in the great huggingface/transformers library.

I am using a [notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/github/huggingface/blog/blob/master/notebooks/trainer/01_text_classification.ipynb#scrollTo=uBzDW1FO63pK), provided by library creators as a starting point for my pipeline. It presents a pipeline of finetuning a BERT for Sentence Classification on Glue dataset.

When getting into the code, I noticed a very weird thing, which I cannot explain.

In the example, input data is introduced to the model as the instances of the `InputFeatures` class from [here](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/011cc0be51cf2eb0a91333f1a731658361e81d89/src/transformers/data/processors/utils.py):

This class has 4 attributes, including the **label** attribute:

```py
class InputFeatures:
    ...
    input_ids: List[int]
    attention_mask: Optional[List[int]] = None
    token_type_ids: Optional[List[int]] = None
    label: Optional[Union[int, float]] = None
```

which are later passed as a dictionary of inputs to the `forward()` method of the model. This is done by the `Trainer` class, for example in the lines 573-576 [here](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/edcb3ac59ab05d9afbc6b4f7bebfb2e5dfc662d2/src/transformers/trainer.py):

```py
    def _training_step(
        self, model: nn.Module, inputs: Dict[str, torch.Tensor], optimizer: torch.optim.Optimizer
    ) -> float:
        model.train()
        for k, v in inputs.items():
            inputs[k] = v.to(self.args.device)

        outputs = model(**inputs)
```

However, the `forward()` method expects **labels** (note the plural form) input parameter (taken from [here](https://huggingface.co/transformers/_modules/transformers/modeling_distilbert.html#DistilBertForSequenceClassification)):

```py
    def forward(
        self,
        input_ids=None,
        attention_mask=None,
        head_mask=None,
        inputs_embeds=None,
        labels=None,
        output_attentions=None,
    ):
```

So my question is **where does the label become labels** in this pipeline?

To give some extra info on the issue, I created my own pipeline, which uses nothing, related, with Glue data and pipe, basically it relies only on the `Trainer` class of transformers. I even use another model (Flaubert). I replicated the InputFeature class and my code works for both cases below:

```py
class InputFeature:
    def __init__(self, text, label):
        self.input_ids = text
        self.label = label

class InputFeaturePlural:
    def __init__(self, text, label):
        self.input_ids = text
        self.labels = label
```

But it does not work if I name the second attribute as `self.labe` or by any other names. **Why is it possible to use both attribute names?**

It's not like it is extremely important in my case, but I feel uncomfortable passing around the data in the variable, which "changes name" somewhere along the way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The rename happens in the `collator`. In the [trainer](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/204ebc25e6520db8261e19290de334487a16a859/src/transformers/trainer.py#L179) init, when `data_collator` is `None`, a default one is used:

```py
class Trainer:
    # ...
    def __init__(...):
        # ...
        self.data_collator = data_collator if data_collator is not None else default_data_collator
        # ...
```

FYI, the `self.data_collator` is later used when you get the [dataloader](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/204ebc25e6520db8261e19290de334487a16a859/src/transformers/trainer.py#L209-L227):

```py
data_loader = DataLoader(
    self.train_dataset,
    batch_size=self.args.train_batch_size,
    sampler=train_sampler,
    collate_fn=self.data_collator,              # <-- here
    drop_last=self.args.dataloader_drop_last,
)
```

The default collator has a [special handling for labels](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/204ebc25e6520db8261e19290de334487a16a859/src/transformers/data/data_collator.py#L38-L54), which does this renaming, if needed:

```py
# Special handling for labels.
# Ensure that tensor is created with the correct type
# (it should be automatically the case, but let's make sure of it.)
if hasattr(first, "label") and first.label is not None:
    if type(first.label) is int:
        labels = torch.tensor([f.label for f in features], dtype=torch.long)
    else:
        labels = torch.tensor([f.label for f in features], dtype=torch.float)
    batch = {"labels": labels}  # <-- here is where it happens
elif hasattr(first, "label_ids") and first.label_ids is not None:
    if type(first.label_ids[0]) is int:
        labels = torch.tensor([f.label_ids for f in features], dtype=torch.long)
    else:
        labels = torch.tensor([f.label_ids for f in features], dtype=torch.float)
    batch = {"labels": labels}
else:
    batch = {}
```